# Web API – authenticate with bearer token

Tags: asp.net-mvc, authentication, oauth-2.0, asp.net-web-api2, owin

I have created a MVC application for allowing external authentication/registration. It has been created with all the necessary components (Owin, EF, register, login, logout) and I am able to perform all the basic activities in the application.

Now, I want to integrate the web application with the Web API which is going to be used by my mobile app too. I stuck in the authentication in the Web API calls (with the bearer token I received from the web application).

I saw examples to create WEB API projects with OWIN middleware enabled. But i dont know how to centralize the external authentication process and use the token for both my web application and the mobile application
And **I don't want to go for the ANGULAR** or Single page application.
Can anyone suggest me the right technical path to fix this issue.
Thank you.

**Step 1:**

I created a MVC project in visual studio 2015 with Individual Login Enabled. And configured the Keys that i configured everything in the google developer console. My **Startup.cs** will have the following code

```
 public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        // Configure the db context, user manager and signin manager to use a single instance per request
        app.CreatePerOwinContext(ApplicationDbContext.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationUserManager>(ApplicationUserManager.Create);
        app.CreatePerOwinContext<ApplicationSignInManager>(ApplicationSignInManager.Create);

        // Enable the application to use a cookie to store information for the signed in user
        // and to use a cookie to temporarily store information about a user logging in with a third party login provider
        // Configure the sign in cookie
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
        {
            AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
            LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login"),
            Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
            {
                // Enables the application to validate the security stamp when the user logs in.
                // This is a security feature which is used when you change a password or add an external login to your account.  
                OnValidateIdentity = SecurityStampValidator.OnValidateIdentity<ApplicationUserManager, ApplicationUser>(
                        validateInterval: TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30),
                        regenerateIdentity: (manager, user) => user.GenerateUserIdentityAsync(manager))
            }
        });
```

**Step 2:**

Changed the webconfig file to point my local DB and run the app, i am able to successfully login through google with my gmail account and user details are added to ASPUSerTables in the DB successfully

**Step 3:**

Now I wanted to create a WEB API Project which will be connected to the DB and retrive some data to the MVC web application and Mobile application (I am stuck on authentication part  here). I need to use third party authentication to my mobile app too (Xamarin) and use the common API from my mobile app and MVC website

**Step 4**
So I thought, Instead of WEB application (Step 1), I should have created WEB API Project which will look like below to return the auth token in **Startup.cs** and store that cookie in the website to pass in the subsequent requests.

```
app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions());
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        // Configure the application for OAuth based flow
        PublicClientId = "self";
        OAuthOptions = new OAuthAuthorizationServerOptions
        {
            TokenEndpointPath = new PathString("/Token"),
            Provider = new ApplicationOAuthProvider(PublicClientId),
            AuthorizeEndpointPath = new PathString("/api/Account/ExternalLogin"),
            AccessTokenExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromDays(14),
            // In production mode set AllowInsecureHttp = false
            AllowInsecureHttp = true
        };
```

I don't want to go with ANGULAR and I need my WebApplication(MVC) and WEB API project Authenticates properly for all the requests. Please advise me the 
right path.
Thanks

Comment: where are you stuck in authentication with bearer token ?? what is the error you are getting that will be helpful to answer you question. I have done projects where both mobile and web use the same Api without any issue.

Comment: Hi Jawand. Thanks for your immediate reply. In my MVC project, I am able to get the user claims from google in my AccountController and able to register the details in ASPUsers tables. I created seperate web api project without owin components (is it right) and need to authorize from the web application. I am not sure how to get the access token in the webapp cookies and authorize the REST calls. Please guide me with the steps to create simple MVC client application (not angular) and web api project to support external authentication in both web and mobile app.

Comment: @DevOne Can you add some of your code to the question?

Comment: Hi. Thanks I have updated it Please let me know if you need more information

Comment: @DevOne i am assuming you want to use standard MVC controller in your web application right ? and you want to call your Web API from MVC controller ? please correct me if i am wrong. this will help me to answer your question.

Comment: Hi Jawand. Yes. I need that exactly. I figured out that if we create a MVC project with WEBAPI Enabled, it gives you all the support functionalities for API projects too.. (API calls with token etc) in that.. But i am still wondering, with this approach i cannot decouplemy WEB API project alone. (I don't want to duplicate OWIN implementation in both my MVC and API projects).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What you need to do is follow these steps

- Create a Web API project with **Individual User Accounts** Authentication.
- Now, you will have all ready to use API's for Register, change password, as well as API endpoint to generate token for a user.
- Create another project but this time it is **MVC** with **No Authentication** in same solution.

well this will be our architecture

[image]

This is API controller

```
[Authorize]
public class ValuesController : ApiController
{
      [HttpGet]
      public IEnumerable<string> Get()
      {
         return new string[] { "values1", "values2" };
      }
}
```

This is your MVC controller

```
public class MVCValuesController : Controller
{
     HttpClient client;

     // web api Url
     string url = string.Format("http://localhost:60143/api/Values");
     string bearerToken = string.Format("bearer token from web api");
     public MVCValuesController()
     {
        client = new HttpClient(); 
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);
     }

     public ActionResult GetValues()
     {
         HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.Get(url);
         if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             var responseData =   responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
             var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(responseData);
             return View(jsonResponse);
         }
         return View("Error");
     }
}
```

I have not used async here, but you can do it. and also you need to start both of your projects when you run it. right click on solution and click `Set Start Up projects` then you can select multiple projects and set action as `Start`.

```
public class MVCAccountController : Controller
{
     HttpClient client;

     // web api Url
     string url = string.Format("http://localhost:60143/");
     //string bearerToken = string.Format("bearer token from web api");
     public MVCValuesController()
     {
        client = new HttpClient(); 
        client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
        client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
         // just adding a JObject you can create a class 

         JObject tokenJobject = new JObject(
                                        new JProperty("Email", "someone@example.com"),
                                        new JProperty("Password", "Pass123"));
                                        new JProperty("ConfirmPassword", "Pass123"));
            HttpContent baseContent = new StringContent(tokenJobject.ToString(), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
        //client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + bearerToken);


     }

     public async Task<ActionResult> GetValues()
     {
         string requestUri = string.Format("api/Account/Register");
         HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = await client.PostAsync(requestUri, baseContent);
         if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
         {
             var responseData =   responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
             var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<string>(responseData);
             return View(jsonResponse);
         }
         return View("Error");
     }
}
```

Comment: Hi Jawand. Thanks for your answer. I have also thought about this solution but I wanted to use all the default features of OWIN such as Registerration, forgot password, reset password, External auth redirection etc. Can I able to still consume all the API functionalities from the MVC application - No authentication application without any hassles? .

Comment: yes, you will be able to use it without any problem. I'll add some more code to answer.

Comment: @DevOne take a look i have used a method from web api named `Register` and used it to register a new user. let me know if you need more help

Comment: Thanks for your efforts. I am looking for reducing the development time for the Registration process otherwise I need to manually do all these in the WEB API. (reset password, forgot password etc..). So I have created the MVC WEB API which has come with all the code. I wanted to have a seperate web api project that could be used by the mobile app and WEB for the other calls. But all the requests should be Authorized. May be i will create another simple API project with **Individual Auth** enabled and have the basic functions for authenticating the tokens in all the requests.Marked as answer!

Comment: @JawandSingh  I have the similar requirement of user authentication from web application and mobile application. Can you please explain me how can I miantain the identity of users in mvc project with No athentication?

Comment: @ArpitGupta so, according to what i understood, you can use Identity `UserManager.Create(user)`, it does not accept password. So, you'll have your users created without password. Now, comes the question how to maintain the identity of users. I will like to know if you are planning for some OAuth kind of things ? then you can maintain the identity of users as you'll have (for example FB) external access token and you can again call FB asking if this is a valid token or not ? that's how you can prevent misuse of the API's. let me know if i you got your answer or not .

Comment: @JawandSingh I have two projects, a mvc application and a web api. Initially I used EF and Identity in my application but I referred your answer and shifted everything to Web APi project. Now my application doesn't use Identity anymore. So I am wondering how to get properties like User.Identity.Name in app.

Comment: Ur declaration of baseContent is wrong as you can not access that futher down the china

Answer (score 1):

```
 public class MVCValuesController : Controller 
 {
       HttpClient client;

       // web api Url
       string url = string.Format("http://localhost:60143/api/Values");
       string bearerToken = string.Format("bearer token from web api");

       public MVCValuesController()
       {
          client = new HttpClient(); 
          client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
          client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", bearerToken);
       }

       public ActionResult GetValues()
       {
          HttpResponseMessage responseMessage = client.Get(url);
          if (responseMessage.IsSuccessStatusCode)
          {
              var responseData =   responseMessage.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
              var jsonResponse = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<string>>(responseData);
              return View(jsonResponse);
          }
          return View("Error");
       }
 }
```

Comment: no explanation, and looks like a copy paste from above answer.